# How to pretty print circular doubly linked list implemented in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-structures, pretty-print

I've implemented a doubly linked list in javascript, however, i'm unable to pretty print my results in nodejs. I'm one of those people who likes visualizing things to fully understand them. I've used prettyjson module from npm for testing my singly LL results which worked out great but it throws max stack error with doubly LL because the data structure is circular. Just wondering, are there any tools or best practices fot better and more accurately testing abstract data structures?

To be more specific, problem i'm having is not being able to visually see my results in terminal (nodejs env) due to data structure i'm testing being circular.
I've tried prettyjson module but it throws "max call stack size reached" error.
I'd like to explore other alternatives for printing my results in nodejs in such a way that it's visually accurate.

PS: I'd like to avoid implementing custom print function/method embedded in my object definition (class/constructor.. however you'd like to call it in Javascript).

In case it's helpful, here my implementation

```js
var prettyjson = require('prettyjson');

//Blueprints
function Node(val){
  this.data = val;
  this.next = null;
  this.prev = null;
}

function DoublyList(){
  this._length = 0;
  this.head = null;
  this.tail = null;
}

//Adds to the list
DoublyList.prototype.add = function(val){
  var node = new Node(val);

  if(this._length){
    this.tail.next = node;
    node.prev = this.tail;
    this.tail = node;
  }else{
    this.head = node;
    this.tail = node;
  }

  this._length++;
  return node;
}

var doublyList = new DoublyList();

doublyList.add(5);
doublyList.add(10);
doublyList.add(15);
doublyList.add(20);
doublyList.add(25);

console.log(doublyList);
```

Comment: What does "print" mean in this case?  What do you expect the output to look like and where did you get stuck when you tried to do it yourself?

Comment: maybe you find this node package useful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/doubly-linked-list You can dive into the code and check its `toString` method

Comment: this is the link to its `toString` method: https://github.com/lmaccherone/DoublyLinkedList/blob/master/DoublyLinkedList.coffee#L64 reach me if you had any doubts

Comment: You might find this useful: https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options

Comment: Thanks @cartant! util.inspect is definitely more in line of what i'm looking for as i'm able to print my object output in more organized and legible way than using JSON.stringify or prettyjson module.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to test your implementation, then you're almost certainly going to have to deal with some fairly messy output as I can't see a good way of visualising that on a command line. If you're just visualising the contents of the list it's not really any different from what you'd do in a normal list; loop over the list and print each element. For example:

```
function printList(doublyList) {
    var nodes = [];
    for (var n = doublyList.head; n != null; n = n.next) {
        nodes.push(n.data);
    }
    console.log(nodes.join('<=>'));
}
```

For more detailed debug information you could add the links both directions:

```
function debugPrintList(doublyList) {
    var nodes = [];
    for (var n = doublyList.head; n != null; n = n.next) {
        var nextData = n.next ? n.next.data : 'undefined';
        var previousData = n.prev ? n.prev.data : 'undefined';
        nodes.push('[data: ' + n.data + '; next: ' + nextData + '; prev: ' + prevData + ']');
    }
    console.log(nodes.join('\n'));
}
```

Or however else you prefer to output it.

I'm not aware of a library function that will do this for you automatically, but as you can see it's not overly complicated to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Thor84no! I'm looking to test my implementation where the nested object is pretty printed fully in terminal in organized and legible manner...

Comment: Well, the `debugPrintList` should do that if `data` is a string. If not you can simply use something like `require('util').inspect(n.data)` to get a formatted version of the data (or pretty print it). Whatever the case, you should certainly be able to modify the output to your liking.